# Client receives only 1440 bytes of stream

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I just recenty started to play with Xamarin after a long time, and I am very happy that it gotten a long way.

I am creating android app with xamarin, and i have weird problem.

My Xamarin app sends stream to windows TCPServer (through socket) containing short string.

TCPServer recognize that string as certain command, and create JSON string(pull some data from database), then send's it back to the Xamarin app.

However, if the stream containing JSON is larger than 1440 bytes it gets cut at 1440 bytes. If JSON is shorter than 1440 it will work just fine.

Then i created windows console application and copy pasted code from Xamarin Client app, send same string command to TCPServer, and got complete JSON 3360 bytes long back..
I tested this with various JSON strings, and everything works if it is received with windows machine regardless of the size (one of strings was 56514 bytes). But on Android, depending on device if it larger than 1440 bytes it will receive just 1440 bytes.

To make things even more interesting, there seems to be different limit depending on type of Android device.

---

Xamarin Emulator - 1440bytes

Sony Xperia - 1460 bytes

Samsung Galaxy A5 - 11680 bytes

---

I wonder if there are some limitations of TCPclient when used in Xamarin, or some setting that I am missing?

TCPServer Code

```
    private void StartLncListener()
    {

        IPAddress myIP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.8");
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(myIP, 8005);
        TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);

        try
        {

            server.Start();
            SetText("Waiting for connection... ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        while (true)
        {
            client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[5000]; //tried to play with this
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            SetText("Client connected...");

            stream.Read(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);
            StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (byte b in receivedBuffer)
            {
                if (b.Equals(00))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    msg.Append(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());
                }

            }

            var ReturnedData = DecodeData(msg.ToString());

            int byteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(ReturnedData);
            byte[] responseMsg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ReturnedData);

            stream.Write(responseMsg, 0, responseMsg.Length);
        }

    }
```

TCPClient Code

```
public string ConnectLnc(string serverIP, int port, String request)
        {

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIP, port);

            int byteCount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(request);
            byte[] sendData = new byte[byteCount];

            sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);

            while (true)
            {
                byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[1000000]; //was 5k, changed to million for test

                stream.Read(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);

                string TMPmsg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);

                StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (byte b in receivedBuffer)
                {
                    if (b.Equals(00))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        msg.Append(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());
                    }

                }

                stream.Close();
                client.Close();

                var len = msg.Length;
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg.ToString());

                return msg.ToString();
            }

        }
```

My English is not the best, so I hope that I managed to explain this properly.

Comment: @mjwills It always returns part of JSON that fits in that 1440 bytes. It is not usefull since it is not formated properly, but I could fix that. Maybe even split JSON into smaller packets and send them to client.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest checking the value returned by `Read`. There is no point looking at an array of `1000000` entries if only 4K entries were written to it, for example. The code could also be cleaned up to, for example, not include unnecessary code like `TMPmsg`.

Comment: Also consider whether the `while (true)` is doing anything useful given you have a `return` inside of it. I suspect what you meant to do was declare `msg` _outside of_ the `while` loop and then also move the `return` **after** the `while` loop.

Comment: @mjwills Yes, thank you. Now it is working properly. I am not finished yet, but code will be shorter for at least 15 lines when I am done. Thank you very much for your time.